# Create custom template for a specific node without node ID?

Tags: theming

I want to create a custom tpl for a specific node. However I dont want to use node id in the file name (page--node--11.tpl.php). Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use [hook_preprocess_node()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) or [hook_preprocess_page()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) to suggest any template you want for a node or a page.  I am suggesting both because of the name you gave in your question `page--node--11.tpl.php` is really a page template not a node template.

Regardless, you could do this:

```
function YOURTHEME_OR_MODULE_preprocess_node(&$variables) { 

  if ( /* whatever logic */ ) {

    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node_whatever_you_want_to_call_it';

  }

}
```

or

```
function YOURTHEME_OR_MODULE_preprocess_page(&$variables) { 

  if ( /* whatever logic */ ) {

    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page_whatever_you_want_to_call_it';

  }

}
```

and now when that node is rendered, it will use `node-whatever-you-want-to-call-it.tpl.php` or if the page, `page-whatever-you-want-to-call-it.tpl.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Check for any attributes you are using to determine if it is the correct node in [template_preprocess_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) (in your themes template.php) and then add to the $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'] array.

Something like this:

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    if(isset($variables['node']) && $variables['node']->your_field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']=='some_value') {
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__your_template';
    }
}
```

Comment: fyi, if you are on `node/###`, `$variables['node']` will already contain the node object, so there isn't much need to `node_load()` it again (even though it is most probably still cached).

Comment: Thanks Jimajamma - I was wondering if there was a node object hiding away in somewhere but couldn't see it - I'll remember that as is useful to know.

Comment: Quite welcome; I find printing out `array_keys($variables)` to be quite helpful in finding out what you have to work in these kinds of drupal hooks.

Comment: I was using dmp() but I think the problem lay with my eyes not the code!